# imagemagick convert как увеличить размер изображения

Tags: imagemagick

есть картинка 1803х900 пикселов, радо из неё сделать картинку 1920x1080 пикселов

соманда convert image1.jpg -resize 1920x1080 -quality 100 output.jpg не помогает, т.к. делает картинку размером 1920х958 пикселов. Т.е. надо растянуть изображение не только по горизонтали, но и по вертикали.

что делать? ибо изображений таких 1500 штук =(

Comment: командп convert image1.jpg -scale 1920x1080 -quality 100 output.jpg также не помогает =(

Comment: [`-resize 1920x1080!`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry)

Answer (score 0):

```
convert in.png -resize 1920x1080^ -gravity center -extent 1920x1080 out.png
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).